# Converting an my service into System service

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have created a Service that needs PowerManager.reboot to reboot the system as and when required. Although I have added "android.permission.REBOOT" permission to my service Manifest file, call from my service fails to achieve the reboot, due to permission issues. How can I solve this permission problem. 
Will my service be able to call reboot method if it converted as system service. If so how to convert a service to system service?

Kindly help !
 JSk

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this permission problem.

Write your own firmware and put your application in as part of that firmware.

> If so how to convert a service to system service?

Rewrite the operating system, as system services are part of the operating system. Then, put your modified operating system in your modified firmware.